# C# ApplyTheme method to work on all forms simultaneously

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm trying to implement a theme changer to my app. So far I've done this:

BaseForm - has all the functions to be inherited from, it's a lengthy one so if required I'll post it here. What troubles I'm having is as follows:

MainForm has a button to open UserSettings where the user can change the theme. Problem is, I managed to get it down that the theme applies, but only for the UserSettings window, and I want it to apply to anything that is open (if there is anything else).

Edit: adding more code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.Versioning;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using IniParser;
using ME___Tooling_Designer_App.Properties;

namespace ME___Tooling_Designer_App.Configuration;

public partial class UserSettings : BaseForm
{
    public UserSettings()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ApplyTheme();
        ReadConfiguration();
    }

// this is where the theme should be applied upon close
private void CBoxTheme_DropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var parser = new FileIniDataParser();

        var data = parser.ReadFile(_filePathSettings);

        if (cBoxTheme.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            data["User_Settings"]["Theme"] = "Dark";
            parser.WriteFile(_filePathSettings, data);
            GlobalTheme = Enumerators.Theme.Dark;
        }

        if (cBoxTheme.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            data["User_Settings"]["Theme"] = "Light";
            parser.WriteFile(_filePathSettings, data);
            GlobalTheme = Enumerators.Theme.Light;
        }
        ApplyTheme();
    }

public override void ApplyThemeSpecific(ThemeSettings settings)
    {
        panel1.BackColor = settings.PrimaryColor;
        label2.ForeColor = settings.PrimaryFontColor;
        btnExit.BackColor = settings.PrimaryColor;
        btnExit.ForeColor = settings.PrimaryFontColor;
        groupBox1.ForeColor = settings.PrimaryFontColor;
        groupBox2.ForeColor = settings.PrimaryFontColor;

        panel2.BackColor = settings.SecondaryColor;
    }
```

Edit: this is BaseForm code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ME___Tooling_Designer_App.Configuration;

public class BaseForm : Form
{

    public static List<PrivateFontCollection> FontCollections;


    public static Enumerators.Theme GlobalTheme { get; set; }

    public void ApplyTheme()
    {
        var settings = new ThemeSettings();

        if (GlobalTheme == Enumerators.Theme.Dark)
        {
            settings.PrimaryColor = Color.FromArgb(32, 30, 50);
            settings.SecondaryColor = Color.FromArgb(32, 30, 45);
            settings.TertiaryColor = Color.FromArgb(11, 7, 17);
            settings.QuaternaryColor = Color.FromArgb(23, 21, 32);
            settings.QuinaryColor = Color.FromArgb(35, 32, 39);
            settings.SenaryColor = Color.LightGray;
            settings.SeptenaryColor = Color.Gainsboro;
            settings.PrimaryFontColor = Color.Gainsboro;
        }

        else if (GlobalTheme == Enumerators.Theme.Light)
        {
            settings.PrimaryColor = Color.LightGray;
            settings.SecondaryColor = Color.GhostWhite;
            settings.TertiaryColor = Color.Gainsboro;
            settings.QuaternaryColor = Color.DarkGray;
            settings.QuinaryColor = Color.Silver;
            settings.SenaryColor = Color.Gray;
            settings.SeptenaryColor = Color.Black;
            settings.PrimaryFontColor = Color.Black;
        }

        ApplyThemeSpecific(settings);
    }

    public virtual void ApplyThemeSpecific(ThemeSettings settings)
    {
    }
}

public class Enumerators
{
    public enum Theme
    {
        NotSet,
        Light,
        Dark
    }
}

public class ThemeSettings
{
    public Color PrimaryColor { get; set; }
    public Color SecondaryColor { get; set; }
    public Color TertiaryColor { get; set; }
    public Color QuaternaryColor { get; set; }
    public Color QuinaryColor { get; set; }
    public Color SenaryColor { get; set; }
    public Color SeptenaryColor { get; set; }
    public Color PrimaryFontColor { get; set; }
}
```

this is my Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using IniParser;
using ME___Tooling_Designer_App.Configuration;
using ME___Tooling_Designer_App.Forms;

namespace ME___Tooling_Designer_App
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {

            var parser = new FileIniDataParser();

            var data = parser.ReadFile(Application.StartupPath + @"\" + "Config" + @"\" + "settings.ini");

            var themeSetting = data["User_Settings"]["Theme"];

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetHighDpiMode(HighDpiMode.SystemAware);
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            if (themeSetting == "Light")
            {
                BaseForm.GlobalTheme = Enumerators.Theme.Light;
            }
            else if (themeSetting == "Dark")
            {
                BaseForm.GlobalTheme = Enumerators.Theme.Dark;
            }
            else
            {
                BaseForm.GlobalTheme = Enumerators.Theme.NotSet;
            }

            Application.Run(new Login());
        }

    }
}
```

tried doing it as MainForm.ApplyTheme, but that just returns to UserSettings nonetheless

Edit: adding snippets of MainForm:

```
namespace ME___Tooling_Designer_App.Forms;

public partial class MainForm : BaseForm
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Constructor
    /// </summary>
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ApplyTheme();
        CreateDirectories();
        CustomizeDesign();
        InitializeDatFiles();
        InitializeIniConfiguration();
        ReadFont();
        ReadComputer();
        ReadSystem();
        TestTrial();
        DaysRemainColoring();
        CompareComputerNameAndLicense();
        lblUser.Text = Environment.UserName;
    }

public override void ApplyThemeSpecific(ThemeSettings settings)
    {
        panelTopBar.BackColor = settings.PrimaryColor;
        btnInfo.BackColor = settings.PrimaryColor;
        btnMinimize.BackColor = settings.PrimaryColor;
        btnExitTop.BackColor = settings.PrimaryColor;

        panelCenter.BackColor = settings.SecondaryColor;

        panelSideMenu.BackColor = settings.TertiaryColor;
        panelSideMenuLogo.BackColor = settings.TertiaryColor;
        btnMainMenu.BackColor = settings.TertiaryColor;
        btnSettings.BackColor = settings.TertiaryColor;
        btnSave.BackColor = settings.TertiaryColor;
        btnLoad.BackColor = settings.TertiaryColor;
        btnExit.BackColor = settings.TertiaryColor;

        panelQuickView.BackColor = settings.QuaternaryColor;

        panelMainMenu.BackColor = settings.QuinaryColor;
        panelSettings.BackColor = settings.QuinaryColor;
        btnNewProject.BackColor = settings.QuinaryColor;
        btnExistingProject.BackColor = settings.QuinaryColor;
        btnReadProject.BackColor = settings.QuinaryColor;
        btnSearchProject.BackColor = settings.QuinaryColor;
        btnUserSettings.BackColor = settings.QuinaryColor;
        btnAppSettings.BackColor = settings.QuinaryColor;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The solution is to add a timer

Because your problem is to update all windows, you just need to add a timer control to each window.

#### Timer:

[image]

#### BaseForm:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp4 {
    public partial class BaseForm : Form {
        public BaseForm () {
            }
        private static Image baseImage=null;
        public static Image BaseImage {
            get {
                return baseImage;
                }
            set {
                baseImage = value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

#### SettingsForm:

```
using System;

namespace WindowsFormsApp4 {
    public partial class SettingsForm : BaseForm {
        public SettingsForm () {
            InitializeComponent();
            }

        private void button1_Click (object sender, EventArgs e) {
            BaseImage = Resource.tiger;
            }

        private void button2_Click (object sender, EventArgs e) {
            BaseImage = Resource.windows;
            }

        private void timer1_Tick (object sender, EventArgs e) {
            this.BackgroundImage = BaseImage;
            }
        }
    }
```

#### Form1:

```
using System;

namespace WindowsFormsApp4 {
    public partial class Form1 : BaseForm {
        public Form1 () {
            InitializeComponent();          
            }
        private void button1_Click (object sender, EventArgs e) {
            SettingsForm settingsForm=new SettingsForm();
            settingsForm.ShowDialog();
            }

        private void timer1_Tick_1 (object sender, EventArgs e) {
                this.BackgroundImage = BaseImage;
            
            }
        }
    }
```

#### Resource.resx:

[image]

#### OutPut:

[image]

#### You can change it according to your needs.

If you have any questions, please comment below, and I will continue to follow up.

Comment: I had some troubles yesterday to figure this out but I was going the right way, a bit different though. Anyways, this works perfectly, only one thing I'd suggest is to start and stop the timers on form open & form close I did it like this: `private void BtnUserSettings_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var userSettings = new UserSettings();
        userSettings.Show();
        HideSubMenu();
        themeTimer.Start();
        userSettings.FormClosed += ThemeTimer_Stop;
    }`

Comment: Don't use timers when you can use events, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code on all forms of your project on Activated and Load events.

Such as, MainForm:

```
    private void MainForm_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         ApplyTheme();
    }
```

**Update**: Try following line on BaseForm, if it works, add override on all forms and change the color values of all elements:

```
public virtual void ApplyThemeSpecific(ThemeSettings settings)
{
     Background = settings.PrimaryColor; //for example
}
```

**Update 2**: Add a timer on all forms that checks theme change, and when theme changes, it changes the visual. Or you can make a event when theme changes.

Comment: didn't work, thing is, going through the debugger, the steps are correct, file gets overwritten to current theme, globaltheme gets updated and it applies the theme, but it only applies the theme on the current user form, I somehow must call this globally

Comment: can you add more code here? Especially about ThemeSettings and BaseForm

Comment: I've added it, please have a look

Comment: thanks. The answer is updated.

Comment: I'm not sure that will work though, as BaseForm is a dummy form only to inherit properties to other forms. The `public override void ApplyThemeSpecific(ThemeSettings settings)` in the rest of the forms are supposed to override the colors, giving that each form has it's unique controls, which may not match in every, and I can't even add that Background as the BaseForm has no controls in it. Though once the theme is applied, any new window will have the new theme applied, it's just for the currently open ones.

Comment: then add the code of ApplyThemeSpecific of MainForm.

Comment: added it, as you can see that specific method applies stuff for the `MainForm` if the `ApplyTheme` is called within `MainForm`

Comment: wait, if you activate (on foreground) the other form the theme applies, not? But do you want to apply the theme in background (inactive) forms?

Comment: basically as you said, I have a large main form, where user will work and can open a settings window as new

Comment: I think the timer will solve

Answer (score 0):

Using a timer is an unnecessary waste of resources.

A better approach is to use an event in a theme class that is triggered as soon as the theme colors change.

All controls that should change their colors depending on the theme register this event accordingly and update themselves only as soon as the event is triggered.

You could handle this easily by adding base classes for all affected control types and then add the corresponding theme handling to them. Thereby you do not need to add any design handling into each single control but you need to change the classes of your controls to the base classes (within the designer.cs) as you did with `MainForm : BaseForm`.

Code:

```
public class ThemeColor {
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public Color Color { get; set; } = Color.Empty;
}

public class ThemeColors : List<ThemeColor> { }

// the theme class is a container for our color handling
// which provides a public event for other classes to register to
// in order to get informed when the colors are updated
public class Theme {
  // properties
  public static Theme Current { get { return _Instance; } } // for singleton

  // fields
  private static readonly Theme _Instance; // for singleton
  private ThemeColors Colors = new(); // your theme colors

  // events
  public static event Action<ThemeColors> ColorsUpdated = _ => { };

  // constructor
  public Theme() {
    // set your default theme here
    Colors.Add(new() {
      Color = Color.DarkGray,
      Name = "FormBackColor"
    });
  }

  // singleton constructor
  // (to ensure, there is only 1 theme instance)
  static Theme() {
    _Instance = new();
  }

  // the getter is called whenever some control needs a color
  public Color GetColor(string name) {
    ThemeColor themeColor = Colors
      .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == name);

    return themeColor != null
      ? themeColor.Color
      : Color.Red; // simplified error handling: when color is not found, it returns red
  }

  // the setter is called after the user changed colors
  // (e.g. via a settings dialog)
  public void SetColors(ThemeColors colors) { 
    Colors = colors;
    ColorsUpdated(colors); // event is triggered here!
  }
}

// this base class inherits from Form in order to have one
// class for all forms where you put your designer logic into
public class BaseForm : Form {
  // constructor
  public BaseForm() { }

  // use onload() for initial adjustments
  protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
    base.OnLoad(e);
    UpdateDesign(); // set initial control colors

    // register event for theme colors update
    Theme.ColorsUpdate += new Action<ThemeColors>(Theme_ColorsUpdated);
  }

  // event handling
  private void Theme_ColorsUpdated(ThemeColors colors)
    UpdateDesign(); // update the design again
  }

  // all your control design code belongs here
  private void UpdateDesign() {
    // sets the background color of the form
    BackColor = Theme.Current.GetColor("FormBackColor");
  }
}
```

Comment: You are right, there are multiple ways to solve the problem.